# Use Dynamic view in all ASP.NET MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I build a dynamic view in my ASP.NET MVC project and I wanted to use it as menu.

I try to use partial view but it don t work when I use this partial view on the layout. Do you have some idea?

I am a newbie on this technology so I try what I see.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? Yes this is possible. Yes this is common. An additional technology that might make it easier: Angular / React

Comment: Please provide a sample of your code that is not working so that you can be provided advice as to where you are going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have the code of HomeController

```
   public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return RedirectToAction("List", "Modules");
            //return View();
        }
```

now you have the code action List  from controller Module

```
  public ActionResult List()
        {
            List<ModulesModel> lstmod = null;

            lstmod = new List<ModulesModel>();
            lstmod.Add(new ModulesModel() { ID = "1", DisPlayName = "TEST1", Uri = "http://localhost:52863/TEST1" });
            lstmod.Add(new ModulesModel() { ID = "2", DisPlayName = "TEST2", Uri = "http://localhost:52863/TEST2" });
            lstmod.Add(new ModulesModel() { ID = "3", DisPlayName = "TEST3", Uri = "http://localhost:52863/TEST3" });
            return View(lstmod);
        }
    }
```

then you have the List.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcTesProject.Models.Modules.ModulesModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@if (Model.Count() > 0)
{
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                         <li><a href="@item.Uri">@item.DisPlayName</a></li>
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I Want to put this view on the Layout. Thanks to this, all view will use the ListView.

Is it possible ?